# APEX with Customer managed ORDS error on Autonomous Database : SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-autonomous-db, oracle-rest-data-services

I want to connect to APEX built on Autonomous Database in the same compartment, After following the steps below to set up Customer Managed ORDS on the compute instance,

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/20.2/aelig/installing-and-configuring-customer-managed-ords-autonomous-database.html

I see the following error when connecting with a browser:

```
#curl  https://158.101.65.62:8443/ords/f?p=100 curl: (35) SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
```

How can this error be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

This issue on Autonomous DB with APEX and customer managed ORDs can be resolved by changing `jetty.port` to `jetty.secure.port` in the standalone.properties file as described in the documented steps you are following. eg:

```
#jetty.port = 8443  
jetty.secure.port = 8443
```